# Executar três funções em um mesmo setInterval

Tags: javascript

Como posso executar três funções dentro do mesmo setInterval, sendo que para uma o tempo para atualizar deve ser diferente.

Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setInterval(resolve, ms));
}
async function update() {
  for($i=0;$i<300;$i++){ // a cada 300x (5min) faz um refresh
      atualizaLeilao();
      atualizaLeilaoCancelado();
      updateClock();
      await sleep(1000);
  }
 location.reload(); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    update();
});
```

Eu preciso que a função `atualizaLeilaoCancelado();` seja atualizada a cada 5 minutos, e não a cada segundo.

Comment: Wendler, desculpe meu comentário sem conhecer sua aplicação como um todo, mas não existe uma falha de lógica aí? A menos que você coloque um setInterval dentro do outro todos vão ser executados no mesmo tempo, por esse trecho de código seria mais simples criar 3 setIntervals aí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para executar o `atualizaLeilaoCancelado()` a cada 5 minutos o mais simples é individualizar essa chamada num `setInterval` à parte com o respetivo valor de intervalo:

```
function updateLeilaoCancelado(){
    setInterval(function(){
        atualizaLeilaoCancelado();
    }, 300000);
}
```

E depois chama os dois no código principal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    update();
    updateLeilaoCancelado();
});
```

Aconselho-o também a rever um pouco dá lógica pois se no `update` após 300 iterações do `for`, que são 5 minutos faz refresh à pagina, então atualizar a cada 5 minutos perde o sentido.